# How to address the columns of an inline array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Suppose you want to run a query against an inline array:

`QUERY({"apple"; "orange"; "banana"}, "select A")`

This yields `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNA`.

Is this type of array even addressable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns of an inline array are addressed as Col1, Col2, Col3, and so on.

```
QUERY({"apple"; "orange"; "banana"}, "select Col1")
```

The same applies to the arrays imported with `importrange`, `importdata`, etc.